Integral of function of Brownian motion
I want to try and prove that
$$M \equiv \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+|B_t|^p} dt = \infty$$ almost surely, where $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is a standard Brownian motion. I conjecture this to be true because one can show (tediously) that $\frac{1}{1+|B_t|^p}$ is a submartingale and we also have $E(M) = \infty$. Furthermore, for any $K > 0$, we have
$$M \ge \frac{1}{1+K^p}\int_0^\infty \mathbf{1}(|B_t| < K) dt$$ and I feel as though the term on the right hand side must diverge simply due to the fact that Brownian motion visits the origin infinitely often (but I cannot rigorously show this).
It is clearly true for the case where $p = 1$, by the Law of the Iterated Logarithm. Again,
$$M \ge \int_T^\infty \frac{1}{3+ \sqrt{2 t \log \log(t)}} dt = \infty$$
where $T$ is chosen such that $\sup_{t \ge T} \frac{|B_t|}{\sqrt{2t\log\log(t)}} \leq 2$. Again, I feel like there is an obvious way to show this in more generality, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Use the fact that $B$ is recurrent to lower bound the integral by a sum of IID.
Let $I_p$ be the integral.
Let $S_0=0$ and continue inductively, $E_n = \inf\{t\ge S_n: |B_t|\ge 1\}, S_{n+1} = \inf\{t> E_n: B_t=0\}$. Since $B$ is recurrent and continuous $S_0< E_0<S_1<E_1<\dots < S_n < E_n < \infty$ a.s. for all $n$.  Let $T_n = E_n - S_n$. Then by the strong Markov property, $(T_n:n=1,2,\dots)$ are IID. Also, $T_n > 0$ a.s. and therefore there exists $\epsilon>0$ (actually, any $\epsilon>0$) such that $c_\epsilon= P(T_n\ge \epsilon) >0$.
Also, for every $p>0$,
$$I_p \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{T_n}{2}\ge \frac{\epsilon}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty {\bf 1}_{\{T_n \ge \epsilon\}},$$
which is equal to $\infty$ by Borel-Cantelli II.

We can prove a much stronger result. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be a function such that $f(0)=1$ and there exists $c$ such that $f(x)>\frac12$ for all $x\in(0,c)$ (in particular, note that continuous functions with $f(0)=1$ satisfy these conditions). Then $$
M = \int_0^\infty f(B_t) \,dt=\infty
$$
almost surely.
Proof: Let $T = \inf\{t\ge 1 \mid B_t = 0\}$ By almost-sure continuity of $B_t$, we have $B_T=0$ almost surely. Then, we have \begin{eqnarray}
M &= &\int_0^1 f(B_t) \, dt + \int_1^T f(B_t)\,dt + \int_T^\infty f(B_t)\,dt \\&\ge& \int_0^1 f(B_t) \, dt +\int_T^\infty f(B_t)\,dt =\int_0^1 f(B_t) \, dt +\int_0^\infty f(B_{t+T})\,dt
\end{eqnarray}
Observe that $\int_0^1 f(B_t) \, dt$ and $\int_0^\infty f(B_{t+T})\,dt$ are independent by the independent increments property. Furthermore, we note that $B_{t+T} \stackrel{d}{=} B_t$. Therefore, if we let $A$ be a random variable with the same distribution as $\int_0^1 f(B_t)\, dt$ but independent of it, we have $$
M \stackrel{d}= A + M
$$
which plainly implies that $M=\infty$ almost surely, since $A>0$ almost surely.

Whys is it true that $B_{t+T} \stackrel{d}{=} B_t$ ? Don't we have $B_{t+T}\mid T \sim \mathcal N(0,t+T) $ ?

Because $B_T=0$ almost surely. Hence $B_{t+T} \mid T = (B_{t+T} - B_T )\mid T \stackrel{d}{=} B_t$
